# Creating a self-extracting executable in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a self-extracting executable in C#.

The requirement is that when I build my C# project, the output of the build should be a self-extracting EXE file which will contain all the files and folders of a predetermined path recursively.

When I run the EXE file generated by building the project, it then extracts all the files to a predetermined folder.

How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: Is the requirement that you need your build to create a self-extracting EXE, or that it has to be in C#?  Because you can use most command-line ZIP tools to create what you want as a post-build step.

Answer (score 4):

You can embed any number of files of arbitrary type into a C# executable, and emit them during  runtime. Here is a good [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140223075628/http://www.cs.nyu.edu/%7Evs667/articles/embed_executable_tutorial). This embedding approach is usually used to pack all DLLs your executable refers to into the executable itself (see e.g. [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200301101042/http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/ch16.aspx)), but it is also appropriate to make a self-extracting executable.

Answer (score -1):

Better use a setup like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). It is easy to use and generates a single EXE file.